# the_post_thumbnail() doesn't seem to work on front-page.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a WordPress theme and I need a section on front-page.php to display the posts.

I have a template section in a folder called "includes" that checks if there are any posts and displays their thumbnails with their respective links. If I call it in the `archive.php` page with `get_template_part()` it works just fine, but I want it in `front-page.php` and that doesn't work for some reason I've been unable to figure out for hours.

This are my files and folders:

[image: Screenshot of files and folders]

This is what's in the `section-portoflio.php` file:

```
<?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post();?>

    <div class="col-6">
        <a id="client-project" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
        </a>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; else: endif;?>
```

This is what's in the `archive.php` file:

```
<?php get_header('project');?>

<div class="container">

      <div class="row"> 
            <?php get_template_part('includes/section-portfolio');?>
      </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

When I try to copy and paste the code above in a div in my `front-page.php` file, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you able get post id or title or nothing display? first check whether the loop is working on front-page by getting any other thing

Comment: I tested the loop by putting some text inside it. It showed up in the front-page.php, so I think it works. Now, about the id, forgive my ignorance but how can I get it?

Comment: @MateusRodrigues instead of displaying the post's thumbnail, test if other data from the post is getting displayed in the front-page.php. Example, try [the_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/).

Comment: @veesar I tried it and it displays "Home". I think I've figured out whats wrong. The function in section-portfolio.php is looking for posts in the current page, that's it works in the archive but not in the home page. But how can I modify the function so it'll work in any page?

Comment: I found this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/220590/loop-code-is-displaying-pages-but-not-actual-posts and it worked. Thank you, @veesar .